# Android - Post status update with media Twitter & Tumblr

Tags: android, twitter, oauth, upload, tumblr

I am trying to allow Android users to post images to Twitter/Tumblr using my app. I am able to authenticate and retrieve user and account info, but I am having trouble with the actual image upload. (Basically I'm ok with all of the HTTP GET api calls, but not the HTTP POST).

I am receiving the following errors (Twitter/Tumblr respectively):

```
"response":{"errors":[{"message":"Error creating status","code":189}]}
"response":{"errors":["Error uploading photo."]},"meta":{"msg":"Bad Request","status":400}
```

Does anyone know what this means? I don't believe it's an authentication error, because I am able to get user info, etc... It looks to me like the problem is with the parameters, presumably media.

I have tried a number of options, including using the image file/data/url, using HttpParams/MultipartEntity, and using "media"/"media[]" but haven't had much success. Below is the current code that I am using. Is there something wrong with my format? Is there something else Twitter/Tumblr is looking for? If anyone has any ideas, suggestions, or improvements, they would be much appreciated. Thanks!

```
private class TwitterShareTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String result = "";
        HttpClient httpclient = GlobalValues.getHttpClient();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json");

        try {
            MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
            entity.addPart("status", new StringBody(ETdescription.getText().toString()));
            entity.addPart("media[]", new FileBody(new File(GlobalValues.getRealPathFromURI(
                    Camera_ShareActivity.this, imageUri))));
            request.setEntity(entity);
            TwitterUtils.getTwitterConsumer().sign(request);

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request, GlobalValues.getLocalContext());
            HttpEntity httpentity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream instream = httpentity.getContent();
            result = GlobalValues.convertStreamToString(instream);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OAuthExpectationFailedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OAuthCommunicationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }

    public void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try {
            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result.trim());
            System.out.println(jObject);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
    }
}
```

~~~ Edit: As requested by YuDroid ~~~

```
private static class TwitterUploadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private File image;
    private String message;
    private OAuthConsumer twitterConsumer;

    public TwitterUploadTask(OAuthConsumer consumer, File file, String string) {
        this.image = file;
        this.message = string;
        this.twitterConsumer = consumer;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String result = "";
        HttpClient httpclient = GlobalValues.getHttpClient();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json");

        ByteArrayInputStream bais = null;
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(image);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis, 8192);
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
            bis.close();
            fis.close();

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
            byte[] myTwitterByteArray = baos.toByteArray();
            bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(myTwitterByteArray);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
            entity.addPart("status", new StringBody(message));
            entity.addPart("media[]", new InputStreamBody(bais, image.getName()));
            request.setEntity(entity);
            twitterConsumer.sign(request);

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request, GlobalValues.getLocalContext());
            HttpEntity httpentity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream instream = httpentity.getContent();
            result = GlobalValues.convertStreamToString(instream);
            Log.i("statuses/update_with_media", result);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OAuthExpectationFailedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OAuthCommunicationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }

    public void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try {
            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result.trim());
            System.out.println(jObject);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: I've solved the problem for Twitter, but I'm still facing issues with Tumblr. From my understanding, Tumblr currently doesn't support MultipartEntity, so we have to use NameValuePairs to add params. Also, Tumblr doesn't support local URLs (which makes sense), so the parameter is 'data,' not 'source'. Currently I am converting the file into a bitmap, converting the bitmap to Byte[] and encoding the Byte[] into a String. I am getting {"response":{"errors":["Error uploading photo."]},"meta":{"msg":"Bad Request","status":400}}. Any ideas?

Comment: How did you solve your uploading image on Twitter problem. Can you share your code with me? It will be too much valuable for me. Thanks

Comment: Hey YuDroid, sorry about that. I added my code as an edit. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for this buddy. Just last night I solved the issue of re-tweet. The problem is that Twitter constantly changes its api and so I also needed to update the corresponding jars viz jTwitter and Twitter4j for my project.. Thanks anyway.. Appy Codding.. :)